# Filter not working with laravel commands

Tags: php, laravel, filter, command

Can we use filters with Laravel commands. It works fine with controllers. But when use with commands it shows error "call to undefined method".
I have this filter customAuth. It works fine in controller by calling    `$this->beforeFilter('podioAuth');`

But when I use this with Laravel commands it shows error. Are filters designed only to work with controllers?

Comment: A little more details and code would be useful

Comment: Why do you need to call a filter on your command (especially one responsible for authentication)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filters are attached to routes and - if the route has a controller action attached - they are in turn made available to the controller. The way in which filters are defined, points this out very well:

```
Route::filter('myFilter', ...);
```

So trying to use `$this->beforeFilter(...)` inside a command will not work, because there is no `beforeFilter` method implemented in `Illuminate\Console\Command`, and more importantly the command itself has no knowledge of filters.